# Incrementar el valor de un campo

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5

El código que tengo en la función es el siguiente:

```
DB::table('projects')
     ->where('order', DB::raw("(select `order` from projects)"))
     ->order + 1;
```

El error que me muestra es el siguiente:

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::$order

¿Cómo puedo corregirlo?

Comment: Hay varios puntos que debes corregir... Para empezar, `order` no es un atributo de la clase `Builder`, deduzco que tendrás que "ejecutar" la consulta antes de obtener ningún valor. Posteriormente tendrás que tomar ese valor, modificarlo y realizar el correspondiente `update` en base de datos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generalmente no es una buena idea utlizar `order` como nombre de un campo, pues en algunos motores es una palabra reservada.

---

Respondiendo a tu inquietud, deberías usar el método increment, disponible en el Query Builder y en Eloquent, si lo que quieres es incrementar TODOS los valores de la columna `order` (le cambié el nombre a `ordering` en mi ejemplo), la siguiente sintaxis debería funcionar:

```
DB::table('projects')-->increment('ordering');
```

Más información en la documentación: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#increment-and-decrement